# Update Stored procedure (T-SQL ) modification automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two identical stored procedures with dynamic query.

Let's say

- Stored procedure A
- Stored procedure B

Both are in different databases. But they have the same code (Not Complete Identical.4-5 lines differ).

Is there a way to update any modification done in stored procedure `A` to stored procedure `B` automatically?

Otherwise I always need to copy and paste changes manually. It is an error-prone activity. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like that:

In database A:

- design your stored procedure in a way, that you have a parameter for
  the database in which you want to do the work

In database B:

- Create a synonym for the procedure in database A

Example:

```
--create procedure in database A
create procedure dbo.StoredProc
(
@dbname --or dbid if you want
)
as
begin
   --create your sql command here, using dynamic sql maybe
   declare @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=N''

   set @sqlcmd = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @dbname + '.dbo.AnyTable'
   exec sp_executesql @sqlcmd
end

--create a synonym for this procedure in database b:
create synonym dbo.StoredProc FOR databaseA.dbo.StoredProc

--then you can call your procedure in Database A and B like this:

declare @dbname NVARCHAR(100) = DB_NAME()

exec dbo.StoredProc @dbname
```

so you have to maintain your code only once, and in database b you only have kind of a "link" to this procedure.

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. is Above method is applicable if stored procedures has slight differences. Let say 5 lines of extra code in stored procedure B ?

Comment: yes it is. just add an if block where you say `if @dbname='databaseB' begin <do additional work here> end`

Comment: the main advantages here are: you only have a procedure for two databases but you can handle permissions as you need in each DB. in Database A people get permission on the procedure, in Database B people get permission for the synonym. nice an clean imho...

Comment: That is SQL Server 2014, not a very general solution.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch what? MSDN: `Applies to: SQL Server 2008 through SQL Server 2016.`

Comment: So the procedure is mandatory to use dynamic SQL to determine the target DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically what SSDT was designed for, the idea is that you write your T-SQL and schema as CREATE statements, you build a "dacpac" and then you use sqlpackage.exe to deploy the dacpac to whatever database you want.

Doing it this way you have an overhead of the SSDT project but it fixes exactly your main problem with the existing method "It is an error-prone activity."

My blog post shows how to get an existing database into SSDT (in this case adventureworks but replace adventureworks with your database):

https://the.agilesql.club/Blog/Ed-Elliott/AdventureWorksCI-Step2-MDF-To-Dot-Sql

Ed